# Install ubuntu on POS system with touch screen

Tags: system-installation, touchscreen

i have a POS system computer (Advanced APT AP15) which already has an ubuntu 12.04 LTS installed and i want to install an 14.04 Ubuntu, i'm using an live USB, when the installer starts the  touch screen does not works,so i can't select "Try Ubuntu" or "install Ubuntu"

My question it's, i can install ubuntu using a USB mouse and then configure the touch screen later? and how i can do that?

Comment: Are you still there?

Comment: maybe if someone that down vote my question has the kindness of tell me why i could learn what not to do the next time ¬¬

Comment: @Seth Why
 exactly did Community protect this?

Answer (score 0):

If it already has 12.04 then you can just upgrade but typing `sudo do-release-upgrade` in a terminal then inputting your password. Also if you can do the install with a mouse then go back to a regular boot, run a dpkg-repack (I'll give you a link in a bit) and save that to a USB then you can reinstall all the drivers later... Just don't blame anyone if you get compatibility issues if you do that.

Comment: thanks, the problem its that i don't have the root password, so for that reason i want to reinstall the system